# Python interpreter resolves imports, PyDev and nosetests don't

Tags: python, import, pydev

I'm using a module from another library I've written in a new library. PyDev and nosetests aren't able to resolve the imports used in my new library, although the Python interpreter is able to do so. The library I'm referencing is stored in my profile site-packages, and I've reconfigured PyDev's PYTHONPATH just to make sure that that folder is included in the path. It is.

The problem looks like this:

My import:

```
import my_library
# Here Eclipse says "ID:E1101  Module 'my_library' has no 'MyClass' member"
print(my_library.MyClass)
# Here Eclipse shows the same error as above
class NewClass(my_library.MyClass):
    ...
```

Nonetheless, if I execute the file in the Eclipse terminal OR in my system terminal, the following is printed:

```
<class 'my_library.my_class.MyClass'>
```

I have tests that are based on an older implementation of the library I'm refactoring and if I run them in the PyDev debugger, they all end with errors. `nosetests` also returns errors, but if I run the tests manually with `python test.py` the tests run.

Here's the output of nosetests:

```
E......
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'MyClass')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 413, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/me/development/eclipse/newLibrary/new_library/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .classes import User, DataPackage
  File "/home/me/development/eclipse/newLibrary/new_library/classes.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .metadata import MetaData
  File "/home/me/development/eclipse/newLibrary/new_library/metadata.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(my_library.MyClass)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MyClass'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.007s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

The PYTHONPATH used by my system and Eclipse seem to be the same (at least I see the site-packages folder that contains my package in my Eclipse settings), and the interpreter is also the same (Python 2.7).

So I see that the import statement works - at least from the command line. But inside Eclipse it doesn't. I've also tried referencing the other project, or dereferencing it, all to no effect. The package import goes through without complaining, but the Eclipse doesn't believe me that the class exists. What's going on?

Comment: Please provide the errors from `nosetests`. Also, what is the result of running `which python` on the terminal? Does this path match the path to Python used by your Eclipse environment and your nose installation (i.e., are they using different Python interpreters and library paths)?

Comment: Hallo and welcome to [import is not resolved in pydev](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bimport+%2Berror+%2Bpydev+is%3Aquestion). I had even went ahead and [reported a bug, complete with testcase](http://sourceforge.net/p/pydev/bugs/1528/). Bottom line : if it runs fine let pydev complain (I did spent quite some time fighting with this and [other](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7645?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel) pydev erroneous error reports)

Comment: Oh okay... That sucks :) But at least it's not my fault. PyDev has a new bug tracker, and I couldn't find the bug report there. Do you know if it's been transferred? Maybe I just can't find it because I'm not at my computer right now.

Comment: I do not think it (they) is (are) there - there are many open bugs in older trackers anyway - feel free to start moving them there :) Btw add @user if you want user to be notified of your comment

Answer (score 0):

The usual problem here is that 'my_library' is not in the PYTHONPATH.

Note that for a library to be imported, its parent folder must be added to the PYTHONPATH.

I.e.: 
if the library has:

```
/folder <-- this is the folder that should be added to the PYTHONPATH.
/folder/my_library
/folder/my_library/__init__.py
```

If it's a folder inside your project, that folder must be set as a source folder in the project properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH

If it's a folder in your system, it should be added in window > preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python (if it's already there, just hit 'apply' to force it to rescan the changes).

Comment: As noted above, my system PYTHONPATH finds the library and executes the script properly. The site-packages folder is also listed in my Eclipse Python interpreter preferences. The structure looks like you've noted above - site-packages, then my_library, then __init__.py.

Comment: Can you print(my_library) to check if it's the module you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, as I show in my question I can not only print the library but also the class I'm importing.

Comment: Can you post the output? (i.e.: add a print(my_library) just before the error and add the output to your question)

Comment: The output has always been in the post, all you have to do is read it :)

Comment: It's not... only the print to the class in the case it succeeds. I want you to add a print for the module in the case it does not succeed.

Comment: As I state in my question, the import always succeeds, but Eclipse claims that it can't resolve the import in the field to the left of the line numbers. I think that Mr_and_Mrs_D have the right answer - that it's a PyDev bug.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood things... I thought that the major issue you had is in the stack-trace where you added `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MyClass'`...

Comment: Yes, that's the place where I have the issue, but the error's not from the stack trace. It's from the IDE itself. The code runs anyway though, it's just not nice seeing errors every time I reference the class while editing. Thanks for the troubleshooting though.